# PHP Array issue when trying to auto select dropdown

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, html-select

**Note**: $i is set earlier in the code and there are 25 drop down boxes, the array shows the first 5 have values, so I need to set those drop downs to selected and show the relevant value.

I have an array that contains the following:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 5 [5] => [6] => [7] => [8] => [9] => [10] => [11] => [12] => [13] => [14] => [15] => [16] => [17] => [18] => [19] => [20] => [21] => [22] => [23] => [24] => )

$i=1;
for ($p=1; $p<=25; $p++){
  for ($pp=1; $pp<=5; $pp++){
   echo "<select id='rqa".$i."".$p."' class='business' name='q".$i."[]' onclick='mand();'> 
    <option value='' selected='selected'>".$rank."</option>
    <option value='".$pp."'"; 
        if (in_array($p, $arr)) echo 'selected';
    echo ">".$pp."</option>";
  }
}
```

All I am trying to do is set set the relevant dropdown as selected and also its value.  Make sense?

All this is doing is setting the first 5 dropdowns to selected but their value is 5, instead on 1,2,3,4,5.

The problem I have having

Comment: You are using $i but it is not initialize any anywhere

Comment: please review your question and code, so I couldn't find `&i`,`$arr` variable declaration and also clear your question!

Comment: $i set much earlier in the code.

Comment: Where is the array to compare your values to? Ok, you have an array 1..25, but where is the actual data for all those 25 select boxes? There should be 25 more arrays available for the default values ... or do the have numbers from 1..? ??

Comment: The 25 dropdowns each have a value of 1 to 5 (as set by $pp).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following code...

```
$arr = array (1,2,3,4,5,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','');
$i=1;
for ($p=1; $p<=25; $p++){
    echo "<br><select id='rqa".$i."".$p."' class='business' name='q".$i."[]' onclick='mand();'>";    
    for ($pp=1; $pp<=5; $pp++){
        $selected = "";
        if ($pp == $arr[$p-1]){
            $selected = "selected='selected'";
        }
        echo "<option value='$pp' ". $selected .">".$pp."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$arr = ARRAY(0=>1, 1=>2, 2=>3, 3=>4, 4=>5, 5=>FALSE, 6=>FALSE);

$i=1;

for ($p=1; $p<=25; $p++){

  $arr_index = $p-1;
  echo "<select id='rqa".$i.$p."' class='business' name='q".$i."[]' onclick='mand();'>";

  for ($pp=1; $pp<=5; $pp++) {
    //<option value='' selected='selected'>".$rank."</option>
    echo "<option value='$pp'";
    if (isset($arr[$arr_index]) AND $pp == $arr[$arr_index]) echo " selected='selected'";
    echo ">".$pp."</option>";
  }

  echo "</select>";
  echo "<br /><br />";

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

---

### 1.I changed the array to code array instead of array output.

### 2.I added the myArray name in the 9'th line.

Try this one:

```
    <?php
$myArray = Array( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 );

for ($p=1; $p<=25; $p++){
  for ($pp=1; $pp<=5; $pp++){
   echo "<select id='rqa".$i."".$p."' class='business' name='q".$i."[]' onclick='mand();'> 
    <option value='' selected='selected'>".$rank."</option>
    <option value='".$pp."'"; 
        if (in_array($p, $myArray)) echo 'selected';
    echo ">".$pp."</option>";
  }
}
?>
```